# How to add attributes set column to category products grid?

Tags: magento-1.7, attributes, products-management, category, product-list

How to add attributes set column to

category products grid
under

Catalog -> Manage Categories -> Category_to_be_edited

I've added a special price since it was already available in the collection.

But I need to have the attribute set also

can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the same module that you used for special price ([explained here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3644/how-to-add-special-price-to-category-products-grid)) you can add you attribute set also.
Just add this to the collection init `->addAttributeToSelect('attribute_set_id')` and the corresponding column in `_prepareColumns()`.

```
$sets = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_set_collection')
            ->setEntityTypeFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getTypeId())
            ->load()
            ->toOptionHash();
    $this->addColumnAfter('set_name',
        array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Attrib. Set Name'),
            'width' => '100px',
            'index' => 'attribute_set_id',
            'type'  => 'options',
            'options' => $sets,
    ), 'name');
```

Comment: you're a PRO man!
Thank you very much!

how could i get to know about the attributes that can be added to filter the collection?

eg.: addAttributeToSelect('attribute_set_id')

Comment: You can basically add any attribute to the collection. Just get the attribute code from `Catalog->Attributes->Manage attributes`. Then just add the grid column with the correct type. The type depends on the attribute type. It can be `text`, `options` (for dropdowns and you need to specify a set of options), `number`, `currency` (for prices), and many others.